# How to capture sqlplus command line output in unix file

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, sed, awk

I am running below : `sqlplus ABC_TT/asfddd@\"SADSS.it.uk.hibm.sdkm:1521/UGJG.UK.HIBM.SDKM\"` 
afte that I am executing one stored procedure `exec HOLD.TRWER`
I want to capture return code of the above stored procedure in unix file as I am running the above commands in unix. Please suggest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I capture a SQLPlus exit code within a shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402610/how-do-i-capture-a-sqlplus-exit-code-within-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store command return value in variable

```
value=`command`
```

And then checking it's value

```
echo "$value"
```

For your case to execute oracle commands within shell script,

```
value=`sqlplus ABC_TT/asfddd@\"SADSS.it.uk.hibm.sdkm:1521/UGJG.UK.HIBM.SDKM\" \
       exec HOLD.TRWER`
```

I'm not sure about the sql query, but you can get the returned results by using

```
value=`oraclecommand`.
```

To print the returned results of oracle command,

```
 echo "$value"
```

To check whether oracle command or any other command executed successfully, just
check with $? value after executing command. Return value is 0 for success and non-zero for failure.

```
if [ $?=0 ]
then 
 echo "Success"
else
 echo "Failure"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for `spool`

```
SQL> spool output.txt
SQL> select 1 from dual;

1
----------
1

SQL> spool off
```

Now after you exit. the query/stroed procedure  output will be stored in a file called output.txt

Answer (score 1):

If by `return code` you mean `output` then:

```
command > file
```

If by `return code` you mean `exit status` then:

```
command
echo "$?" > file
```

If you mean something else, let us know.

Comment: For Unix script we capture the command output by command > file, but how to capture when we have connected to oracle.