# Error out shell script if plsql program fails

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, ksh

In the shell script, I am calling a PLSQL stored procedure

sqlplus -s <

But when there is an error in the plsql block, I need to error out shell script which is running as a host concurrent program in oracle but it is not doing so.

I am new to the shell script and any help is really appreciated.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402610/how-do-i-capture-a-sqlplus-exit-code-within-a-shell-script).

Answer (score 1):

How about using `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT N` in your SQL script?  This returns N to your shell script.

Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I really appreciate your time... I already used this and still my shell script completes successfully even i have an error in plsql code

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no simple, easy way to do this.  SQLPLUS mostly returns success (0) regardless of the status of the underlying PL/SQL commands.  Even using the 'WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT' does not pass that error numerical status back up to the calling shell.

SQLPLUS returns 0 because it was able to successfully execute the command.

However, I have found a way around this, but you need to create a log file from your sql session and then grep out the error.

```
sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOD >> ${sql_local_output_file}
....

  PROCEDURE error( p_msg VARCHAR2 ) IS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE
            error_date    VARCHAR2(20);
        BEGIN
            SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') INTO error_date FROM DUAL;
            dbms_output.put_line( '[' || error_date || ']: ERROR  ' || p_msg );
        END;
    END error;

....
EOD

if (grep -q -e "ERROR" ${sql_local_output_file}); then
    logInfo "Error found in sql script, ( ${sh_script} )."  
fi
```