# WHENEVER SQLERROR never works

Tags: oracle, bash, error-handling, sqlplus, whenever

I don't know what can be a reason and I spent already hours on the Web trying to figure out what's wrong in my case.
I've checked [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm) and some [thought from Tom Kyte](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2010/04/new-thing-about-sqlplus.html) on this and surely [topic on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402610/how-do-i-capture-a-sqlplus-exit-code-within-a-shell-script) about it.

I use following code:

```
.. < <(sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
         set errorlogging on
         WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE
         WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
         connect ${use}/${pwd}@${database}
         @$SCRIPTS_PATH/script.sql
         EOF
          )

echo Exited with $?
```

I've emulated different failure scenarios such as :

- used a wrong user name
- made syntax error in the sql squery

But this guy all the time returns the same result:

```
Exited with 0
```

I've tried different ways, such as

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
```

and so on but none of them worked.

Most of the people on internet say that this works for them.
So I'm getting confused here...

Probably, this feature somehow related with the version of my SQL*Plus / Oracle /  shell / Unix. But I didn't encounter information about such restrictions.

What am I missing here?

If anybody can share any ideas I'll be very grateful.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below generic snippet:

```
$ cmd1 < <(cmd2) # Or cmd1 <(cmd2)
$ echo $?
```

Here, `$?` is set to the exit status of `cmd1`. The exit status of `cmd2` is lost.

In your case, `sqlplus` happens to be cmd2. So, the exit status of that command is not captured in `$?`.

You could try this;

```
$ sqlplus ... | cmd1
$ status=(${PIPESTATUS[@]})
$ for i in ${status[@]}; do
>     [ $i -ne 0 ] && echo Exited with $i
> done
$ echo Exited with 0
```

Note that if `cmd1` is a complex structure (like `while read` e.g.) any thing you run in that while loop will be run in a subshell & any environment (variables/ pwd) changed will be lost.

Comment: Also have a look at this post for alternate options: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128560/how-do-i-capture-the-exit-code-handle-errors-correctly-when-using-process-subs

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I didn't know that 'subshelled' processes return status code in ${PIPESTATUS[@]}. And have read information about it.

Yes, I use while read -r construction. 
So, in overall, what I need to do is read data from oracle table and process rows one by one. But in case if some issue happens during the reading of data I want to react accordingly.

Looks like that in suggested by you construction ${PIPESTATUS[@]} will catch error code from cmd1, NOT from sqlplus.

Comment: Taking into account the capabilities of ${PIPESTATUS[@]} I've tried to follwing:

${PIPESTATUS[@]}

while read -r line; do

if [ ${PIPESTATUS[@]} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo Pipe failed with status code ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
    exit 1
fi

[commands]

done < <(sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
         set errorlogging on
         WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE
         WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
         connect ${use}/${pwd}@${database}
         @$SCRIPTS_PATH/script.sql
         EOF
          )

But evn when I emulate errors in sqlplus, {PIPESTATUS[@]} still always returns 0.

Comment: Yes, I've read on some article that ${PIPESTATUS[@]} is very sensitive variable and should be checked in the first order after pipe. And first thing I do inside the loop - checl its status.
And anyway it returns 0.

What am I missing this time?